# reset grid state in kendo grid angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-angular-ui

We are using kendo grid for Angular and displaying the results based on some input criteria (input some fields in the form and click on button to fetch results and display in grid). For the first time grid displays the first page.

If we change the search criteria and fetches the results, the grid still displays the previous page index and not reset to first page.

EX: We set the pageSize as 10. In the first search request we get 100 records. So displayed 10 pages. I select 8'th page

```
   In the second search request we get only 40 records displaying 4 pages. But no data is displayed in the grid unless we click on any of the 4 paging buttons         as it is still considering the page index as 8.
```

this.state.skip=0